# How to integrate kubernetes cloud plugin with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to integrate Jenkins with K8 secrets in a dedicated namespace but even after creating the service account and secret, I still see Test Connection failures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the jenkins global credential with the secret for the cluster to be authenticated. Do try using default namespace initially. Also double check your k8 url by running #kubectl cluster-info.